# How to Manage Keyboard Interrupt Error in python pynput module

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I have a program which runs in thee background and monitors my keypresses so when I click a specific pattern of keys it runs another program
Now the problem I am having is that if I press Ctrl+C the program terminates due to KeyboardInterrupt so
is there a way in which the program just ignores the KeyboardInterrupt and continues executing

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception KeyboardInterruptError and do what you need to do.

Comment: (https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt)

Comment: I already trie putting the code in a try and except block but the program still stops exectution when i press Ctrl+C

Comment: in your exception block try to print the error name and catch the error.